# SQL Server 2008 : Update query is not working and there is no ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have 2 tables with more than 6 million entries:

Table name: `ONE`

```
   ID   Domain Status
   ------------------
    1    xyz     1
    2    abc    -1
    3    fgh     0
```

Status has (1, -1, 0) values.

Table name: `TWO`

```
    ID   Domain  level  code
    -------------------------
    60    xyz       0    404
```

My goal: update ONE.status for ONE.domain = TWO.domain where TWO.ID = ?, TWO.level=? and TWO.code = ?.

My query:

```
UPDATE ONE   
SET status = -1   
WHERE domain IN (SELECT domain 
                 FROM TWO
                 WHERE id = 88
                   AND level = 0 
                   AND code in (403, 404));
```

My problem:

- This query doesn't throw any errors.
- Execution starts and it just never ends.
- Running subquery separately and feeding result to main query works in under 5 seconds.
- I tried analyzing the query and its taking too long while comparing domains.

**My question**: is there any other way(different approach) to do the same operation more efficiently?

EDIT 1:

ONE.domain has unique values but TWO.domain does not have unique values so i don't think we can use JOIN. Both tables are indexed.

Comment: Your query appears to be written correctly, there just isn't any data matching you values for table TWO in your example, so there are no corresponding matching rows in table ONE to update.  Specifically, there is no row where TWO.ID=88 is your sample data.

Comment: Is there any chance of TWO.Domain being null? If there are any NULL values returned by the SELECT within the IN clause, everything "falls through" and nothing will be updated.

Comment: That makes sense and yes i do have NULL values in TWO.domain and TWO.level. But than is there a way to include this case in query? like if there is NULL value ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for responding guys, You all were on point but your solutions did not work for me. This worked for me:

```
UPDATE ONE t1 
        JOIN TWO t2 ON t1.domain = t2.domain
   SET t1.status = -1
 WHERE t2.ID = 88 
   AND t2.level = 0
   AND t2.code IN (403, 404);
```

I just did JOIN before SET In the query given by you guys. This query takes half second to execute and my original was taking hrs. This query works even if I have NULL values in columns.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this:

```
UPDATE
    one
SET
    one.Status = -1
FROM
    one
JOIN
    two ON one.Domain = two.Domain
WHERE
    two.ID = ? AND two.Level = ? AND two.CODE = ?
```

It's different from your attempt in that it uses an explicit `JOIN` instead of the `WHERE IN`, which are very different unless `two.Domain` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an index.  And, if table `TWO` doesn't have duplicates, then use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE ONE
    SET crawler_status_code = -1
    FROM one t1 JOIN
         two t2
         ON t1.domain = t2.domain
    WHERE t2.id = 88 AND t2.level = 0 AND code in (403, 404));
```

An index on `two(id, level, code, domain)` might prove very helpful.  A similar index should work on your version of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think duplicate would break the join
Try this
AND ONE.crawler_status_code != -1 makes it more efficient as it can skip those rows and not take a lock

```
UPDATE ONE   
SET ONE.Status = -1   
FROM ONE              
JOIN TWO
 ON one.Domain = two.Domain
WHERE TWO.id = 88
AND TWO.level = 0 
AND TWO.code in (403,404))
AND ONE.Status  != -1
```

Comment: This is giving me syntax error near from for some reason.

Comment: @sachinmakasana see update and report syntax error if is does not work

Comment: Still error:  SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM domain_unique_id t1
  JOIN l_webcrawler_status t2
     ON t1.domain' at line 3
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Comment: Don't know  what to say.  There is not even t1 in my query.

Comment: @sachinmakasana the error you see is from some statement in the same batch as the code you are trying to use from paparazzi. Be sure to use it in a new batch to prevent this or comment out your other code.